# How to setup form with multiple Checkboxes which only one can be "checked" with Material-UI components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to build simple form using Material-UI which has:

- multiple options, checkboxes
- only one option can be true, checked

And then, basing on which option is checked I want to push certain information to my `formData` and send it to my backend on `handleSubmit`

My Form component looks like this:

```js
const MyFormComponent= () => {

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ reason: "", feedback: ""});
  const [checkboxesState, setCheckboxesState] = useState({ 
    one: false,
    two: false,
    three: false 
  })

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    /* ... */
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    /* ... */
  }

  return ( 
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

        <Grid container>

          <FormLabel component="legend"> Some asked question here? </FormLabel>
          <FormGroup>
            <FormControlLabel
              control={<Checkbox checked={checkboxesState.one} color="primary" onChange={handleChange} name="one" />}
              label="Label for my first checkbox"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              control={<Checkbox checked={checkboxesState.two} color="primary" onChange={handleChange} name="two" />}
              label="Label for my secound checkbox"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              control={<Checkbox checked={checkboxesState.three} color="primary" onChange={handleChange} name="three" />}
              label="Label for my third checkbox"
            />
          </FormGroup>
        </Grid>

        <ButtonWrapper>
          <Button variant="outlined" color="secondary" type="submit"> Delete </Button>
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary"> Go back </Button>
        </ButtonWrapper>

      </form>
    </>
   );
}
```

So I came up with solution on my `handleChange` like this, works perfectly fine, but I will have to create another `if(/* */) else if(/* */) else if(/* */)` instruction on my `handleSubmit`.

I believe there is much more elegant solution based on Material-UI components API which I don't know yet or don't know how to use it. Can someone suggest me something else in this situation?

```js
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if(e.target.name === "one") {
      setCheckboxesState({
        one: e.target.checked,
        two: false,
        three: false
      });
    } else if (e.target.name === "two") {
      setCheckboxesState({
        one: false,
        two: e.target.checked,
        three: false
      });
    } else if (e.target.name === "three") {
      setCheckboxesState({
        one: false,
        two: false,
        three: e.target.checked
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to achieve "Multiple options, only one selected", Radio Buttons is a better UX choice for that scenario.

Quoting from https://www.nngroup.com/articles/checkboxes-vs-radio-buttons/

> Radio buttons are used when there is a list of two or more options
> that are mutually exclusive and the user must select exactly one
> choice. In other words, clicking a non-selected radio button will
> deselect whatever other button was previously selected in the list.
>
> Checkboxes are used when there are lists of options and the user may
> select any number of choices, including zero, one, or several. In
> other words, each checkbox is independent of all other checkboxes in
> the list, so checking one box doesn't uncheck the others.

To achieve Radio group using Material UI, please refer to [Material UI docs](https://material-ui.com/components/radio-buttons/). They have excellent examples.

```
import React from 'react';
import Radio from '@material-ui/core/Radio';
import RadioGroup from '@material-ui/core/RadioGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import FormLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormLabel';

export default function RadioButtonsGroup() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('female');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <FormControl component="fieldset">
      <FormLabel component="legend">Gender</FormLabel>
      <RadioGroup aria-label="gender" name="gender1" value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
        <FormControlLabel value="female" control={<Radio />} label="Female" />
        <FormControlLabel value="male" control={<Radio />} label="Male" />
        <FormControlLabel value="other" control={<Radio />} label="Other" />
        <FormControlLabel value="disabled" disabled control={<Radio />} label="(Disabled option)" />
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could track the current select checkbox with one variable instead of multiple.

```
const MyFormComponent= () => {

const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ reason: "", feedback: ""});
const [checkboxesState, setCheckboxesState] = useState(-1)

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  /* ... */
};

 const handleChange = (e) => {
  setCheckboxesState(e.target.name);
 }

 return ( 
<>
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

    <Grid container>

      <FormLabel component="legend"> Some asked question here? </FormLabel>
      <FormGroup>
        <FormControlLabel
          control={<Checkbox checked={checkboxesState === 0} color="primary" onChange={handleChange} name={0} />}
          label="Label for my first checkbox"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          control={<Checkbox checked={checkboxesState === 1} color="primary" onChange={handleChange} name={1} />}
          label="Label for my secound checkbox"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          control={<Checkbox checked={checkboxesState === 2} color="primary" onChange={handleChange} name={2} />}
          label="Label for my third checkbox"
        />
      </FormGroup>
    </Grid>

    <ButtonWrapper>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="secondary" type="submit"> Delete </Button>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary"> Go back </Button>
    </ButtonWrapper>

  </form>
</>
 );
```

}